# Char pointer to String in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, parameter-passing

```
typedef struct {
    char *title;
    char *desc;
} RoomData;
RoomData roomData;
GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(roomData.title);

//INSIDE THE GAME.C FILE
int GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(char *title) {
    title = &gameData.title[0];
    return strlen(title);
}
```

So for some reason when I call the GameGetCurretRoomTitle() function it isn't properly being able to print out the contents of roomData.title, it prints NULL. BUT when I print out the 'title' var inside the function itself it works... I have included all the correct files, headers, and ALL the syntax is correct in the full code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters of a function are its local variables. You may imagine this function definition

```
int GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(char *title) {
    title = &gameData.title[0];
    return strlen(title);
}
```

and its call

```
GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(roomData.title);
```

like

```
GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(roomData.title);
//...
int GameGetCurrentRoomTitle() {
    char *title = roomData.title;
    title = &gameData.title[0];
    return strlen(title);
}
```

After exiting the function its local variable title will be destroyed.

If you want that the original pointer would be changed you have to pass its address. In this case the function definition and its call will look like

```
GameGetCurrentRoomTitle( &roomData.title );
//...
int GameGetCurrentRoomTitle( char **title ) {
    *title = &gameData.title[0];
    return strlen( *title );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`C` uses pass-by-value for function argument passing. If you want to change the *value* of `roomData.title` variable itself from `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle()` function, you've to pass a pointer to `roomData.title`. Then you can use `strdup()` to copy the contents of `gameData.title[0]` to `title` inside `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle()`. You need to remember to free the pointer afterwards.

Otherwise, you can allocate memory to `title` before passing that to `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle()` and then  inside `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle()`use `strcpy()`  to copy the string from `gameData.title[0]`.

You need to change `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle()` function accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value of the variable inside the function doesn't change the value of the variable in the caller.

You need to use strcpy to copy the title to the buffer passed into the function. Don't just change the local pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `gameData.title` is an array of pointers to `char` arrays

Then `gameData.title[0]` holds a pointer to a `char` array that exists "somewhere" in memory. Let's say the title is "Foobar" and this is where it is in memory:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Let's say that the bytes, or `char`s, immediately before and after the title are unset and unused by the program at this very moment in time, and that the empty slots above for them means just that.

Now, let's call the pointer to a `char` array that is in `gameData.title[0]` for `p1`. It is pointing at the "Foobar" `char` array, like this:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
             ^
             |
             +-----------+
                         |
   [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][p1][p2][p3][p4][ ]
```

The pointers p2-p4 are the rest of the `char` pointers in the `gameData.title` array.

Now, you have 2 more interesting pointers in your scenario. First, the `roomData.title` `char` pointer. Let's call it `pA` for simplicity. When you pass it to `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle`, it's unset and points at an undefined `char` in the memory space:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
             ^
             |
             +------------+
                          |
   [ ][pA][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][p1][p2][p3][p4][ ]
       |
       +---------+
                 |
                 v
             [ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Second, the `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle` title `char` pointer parameter. Let's call it `pB` for simplicity. When you pass `pA` as an argument to `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle`, its value is copied to `pB`. Its value is not the contents of the memory it points at, but the address it points at. This means that `pB` will point at the same undefined `char` in the memory space as `pA` does:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
             ^
             |
             +-------------+
                           |
   [ ][pA][ ][ ][ ][pB][ ][p1][p2][p3][p4][ ]
       |            |
       +---------+--+
                 |
                 v
             [ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Next, in the body of `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle`, you reassign `pB` (the local title `char` pointer) to point at the same memory location as `p1` (the pointer to a `char` array that is in `gameData.title[0]`):

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
             ^
             |
             +------+------+
                    |      |
   [ ][pA][ ][ ][ ][pB][ ][p1][p2][p3][p4][ ]
       |            
       +---------+
                 |
                 v
             [ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

And, when `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle` finally returns to its caller, `pA` is still pointing at the same undefined memory location.

The fix you miss is to pass a *pointer* to `pA` to `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle` instead of just `pA` itself, and instead of reassigning `pB` to point at the same memory location as `p1`, you should *dereference* `pB` and assign `p1` to that memory location, which is the memory location where the value of the `pA` variable is stored. That way, when `GameGetCurrentRoomTitle` returns, `pA` will see the string you expected.

With "graphics", the new situation would be that `pB` doesn't point at a `char` array, but at a *pointer* to a `char` array. We know that `pA` is that pointer to a `char` array:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
             ^
             |
             +-------------+
                           |
   [ ][pA][ ][ ][ ][pB][ ][p1][p2][p3][p4][ ]
       ^            |
       |            |
       +------------+
```

By assigning something to the dereferenced `pB`, you effectively assign to the memory location it points at, not to `pB` itself. So assigning `p1` to the deferenced `pB` is the same as assigning it to `pA` in this scenario:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][F][o][o][b][a][r][\0][ ][ ][ ][ ]
             ^
             |
       +-----+-------------+
       |                   |
   [ ][pA][ ][ ][ ][pB][ ][p1][p2][p3][p4][ ]
```

And in code:

```
GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(&roomData.title); // pass pointer to 'pA'

int GameGetCurrentRoomTitle(char **title) // 'pB' is a pointer to pointer
{ 
    *title = &gameData.title[0];         // assign 'p1' to dereferenced 'pB'
    return strlen(*title);               // measure dereferenced 'pB'
}
```